# How to get mapping of index alias

Tags: java, elasticsearch

What is the best way to get mapping for [index alias](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html) using java sdk.

The following code :

```
  public MappingMetaData mapping() throws ApiException {
    log.info("Calling mappings endpoint for index ");
    ClusterState cs = client().admin().cluster().prepareState()
            .setIndices("INDEX_NAME").execute().actionGet().getState();
    IndexMetaData imd = cs.getMetaData().index("INDEX_NAME");
    return imd.mapping("INDEX_NAME");
  }
```

returns java.lang.NullPointerException.

If using http version

```
http://ES_SERVER:9200/INDEX_NAME/INDEX_TYPE/_mapping
```

instead of java sdk it works OK and alias is automatically expanded to the real physical index.

Thanks for your help.

elasticsearch version used 1.2.1

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this：

```
ClusterState state = client.admin().cluster().prepareState().get().getState();
    ImmutableOpenMap<String, MappingMetaData> mappings = state.getMetaData().index("your-index-name").getMappings();
    for (ObjectObjectCursor<String, MappingMetaData> mapping : mappings) {
        Object o = JSONObject.toJSON(mapping.value.getSourceAsMap());
        System.out.println(o);
    }
```